# Creating related objects on create with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Basically, I'm trying to create an object with realted objects in one request in DRF, something I thought would be quite simple.

In the example below, I want to create a `Race` with multiple `RaceCar`s

The research and other questions I've looked at all say the following should work, can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

I'm gettting a KeyError for `racecars` when trying to `pop` from `validated_data`, in other words `validated_data` doesn't contain `racecars`.

I can do the logic in the create method on the view, but this seems the more sensible place to do it and I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

The setup is as follows:

**models.py**

```py
class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    team = models.CharField()


class RaceCar(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField()
    driver = models.ForeignKey()
    race = models.ForeignKey(related_name='racecars')


class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class RaceCarSerializer(models.Model):
    driver = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Driver.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = RaceCar
        fields = 'driver', 'color'


class RaceCreateSerializer(models.Model):
    racecars = RaceCarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Race
        fields = 'name', 'racecars'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        racecars = validated_data.pop('racecars')
        instance = Race.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for racecar_data in racecars:
            RaceCar.objects.create(race=instance, **racecar_data)
        return instance
```

**POST data**

```py
{
    'name': 'Gold Cup',
    'racecars': [
        {'driver': 1, 'color': 'blue'},
        {'driver': 4, 'color': 'red'}
    ]
}
```

**views.py**

```py
class RaceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint for Races.
    """

    model = Race

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == LIST_TYPE:
            return RaceListSerializer
        elif self.action in {CREATE_TYPE, OPTIONS_TYPE}:
            return RaceCreateSerializer
        else:
            return RaceDetailSerializer
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your views?

Comment: Try changing your racecars custom field to be racecars_set, everywhere in the serializer.

Comment: Added views @Ken4scholars. @Matt Gleason I want to use `racecars`, that's my point, I don't know why `racecars` is being popped out of the validated_data.

Comment: @TomHamiltonStubber Can you add `read_only=False` and `required=True` option in `racecars = RaceCarSerializer(many=True)`? Please do and share the result

Comment: `'racecars': ['This field is required.']`. It's still not there in the validated_data.